# Repo queryable only returns rows for the first 2 records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a repo setup for a parent object (season). That season object contains a child object (schedule). Then that object has a child object called Match.

When retrieving records via

```
season.Schedules.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Week == 1).ToList();
```

It's only returning "Match" records for the first 2 schedules. If I go to SSMS, it's returning the "Match" records for ALL of the schedules.

Here are the mappings for the objects:

Season:

```
HasMany(x => x.Schedules).KeyColumn("SeasonId");
```

Schedule:

```
HasOne(x => x.Match).ForeignKey("MatchId");
```

Here's my view where I try and iterate over the matches, where the first 2 work, and all the remaining "Match" objects are null (but they are populated when "querying" in SSMS.

```
@model LeagueManager.Models.MatchModel
@foreach (var schedule in Model.Schedules.Where(s => s.Week == 1))
        {
            <div class="row">@schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game1.PlayerA.DisplayName vs @schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game1.PlayerB.DisplayName</div>
            <div class="row">@schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game2.PlayerA.DisplayName vs @schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game2.PlayerB.DisplayName</div>
            <div class="row">@schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game3.PlayerA.DisplayName vs @schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game3.PlayerB.DisplayName</div>
            <div class="row">@schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game4.PlayerA.DisplayName vs @schedule.Match.MatchResults25Game.Game4.PlayerB.DisplayName</div>
            ........
}
```

What are some ways to help me figure out why it's not returning all of the "Match" values, or is there something wrong with how I have everything setup (I wouldn't think so since the first 2 records come back ok...)

Let me know if more background information is needed.

**UPDATE**
Here's what I get from Express Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT schedules0_.SeasonId as SeasonId2_,
schedules0_.ScheduleId as ScheduleId2_,
schedules0_.ScheduleId as ScheduleId12_1_,
schedules0_.Week as Week12_1_,
schedules0_.MatchNumber as MatchNum3_12_1_,
schedules0_.MatchDate as MatchDate12_1_,
schedules0_.SeasonId as SeasonId12_1_,
schedules0_.TeamA as TeamA12_1_,
schedules0_.TeamB as TeamB12_1_,
match1_.MatchId as MatchId3_0_,
match1_.MatchResults25GameId as MatchRes2_3_0_
FROM Schedule schedules0_
left outer join Match match1_ on schedules0_.ScheduleId=match1_.MatchId
WHERE schedules0_.SeasonId=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
go
```

Comment: Look at the generated SQL that NHibernate is producing and then show us that and what SQL you need.

Comment: As a general consideration, your view should only be interacting with ViewModel objects and not with any DB Repository. Maybe it is exactly what you are doing, hitting only objects already loaded in memory for display logic. This would explain why you get different results tahn from hiing the DB

Comment: Are you sure you have  a one-to-one relationship between schedule and match (HasOne)? If not, I would replace `HasOne` with `References` instead (Many-to-one)

Comment: @rivarolle yes, it's one glaring mistake I made when architecting the database structure. I think I'm too far along to fix because the "Schedule" table is not needed (should be renamed to "Match", because all Match contains is ScheduleId and MatchResults25GameId.

Comment: @Rippo I'll try and get to this tonight. Didn't have a chance last night.

Comment: @Rippo profiler results have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the generated `SQL` that NHibernate is producing as I am sure you will find the two queries are different.

You can either enable log4net, download [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) or look at SQL Profiler (if using SQL server).

Answer (score 0):

Aw snap! I figured it out. What I didn't show you is that the Schedule table does NOT contain the MatchId column, and that's what I was mapping the two tables with. It should have been ScheduleId, which both tables contains...

Comment: Ah so the generated SQL showed you the way! I totally recommend using a profiler such as `NHProf` with NHibernate. It has saved my bacon many times ;)

Comment: @Rippo Yes it did. Could that be considered an "answer" so I can give you points?

Comment: if it helped and got you to an answer then yes it is a answer that can be accepted. Have answered below. Thanks